# undefined reference to function Interface::Interface(int)

Tags: c++

I'm new to the concept of proxy classes in c++ and when i tried a program i got errors like undefined reference to function. I do not know where i went wrong in the program, please help me to rectify those errors.

```
undefined reference to `Interface::Interface(int)'
undefined reference to `Interface::getValue() const'
undefined reference to `Interface::setVale(int)'
undefined reference to `Interface::~Interface()'
```

The codes are as follows

Implementation.h

```
#ifndef IMPLEMENTATION_H_INCLUDED
#define IMPLEMENTATION_H_INCLUDED

class Implementation
{
public:
    Implementation(int v):value (v){}
void setValue(int v)
{
    value=v;
}
int getValue()const{
    return value;
}
private:
    int value;
};

 #endif // IMPLEMENTATION_H_INCLUDED
```

Interface.h

```
    #ifndef INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
    #define INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED

    class Implementation;
    class Interface
    {
        private:
        Implementation *ptr;
    public:
        Interface(int);
        void setValue(int);
        int getValue() const;
        ~Interface();

    };

    #endif // INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
```

Interface.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Interface.h"
#include"Implementation.h"
using namespace std;

Interface::Interface(int v):ptr(new Implementation(int v))
{
}

void Interface::setValue(int v)
{
    ptr->setValue(v);
}
int Interface::getValue()const
{
    return ptr->getValue();
}

Interface::~Interface()
{
    delete ptr;
}
```

and here goes the main function
MainFunction.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Interface.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Interface i(2);

    cout<<"Interface Contains:"<<i.getValue()<<"before setValue"<<endl;

    i.setValue(10);

    cout<<"Interface contains:"<<i.getValue()<<"after setValue"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you forgot to add Interface.cpp to your build.

Comment: Can you show your compilation command line

Comment: On a side note... `{ Interface x(1); Interface y = x; } // oops, double delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Use command `g++ MainFunction.cpp Interface.cpp` for compilation and also definition of Interface constructor should be `Interface::Interface(int v):ptr(new Implementation(v))` .

Comment: Ok, I removed int from the definition.Again i got the same error. If I include Interface.cpp instead of Interface.h in my MainFunction.cpp it works well, but if i use Interface.h it raises to error. why is it so ?

Comment: @user3709600 Have you included  Interface.cpp during compilation , could you please show your command to compile above program.

Comment: @user3709600 and when you are including Interface.cpp in MainFunction.cpp it means that you have include code written inside Interface.cpp in your main file so as Interface.cpp is including Interface.h , so both class and its function definition would include in you main file due to which you compilation works.

Comment: I'm using code blocks to run this program. I run only MainFunction.cpp